# Select key from dictionary after sorting it by both value criteria and key criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

From a `dict` *(in Python 2.7)*, how can I select the key whose value is sorted by multiple criteria – if there are several equal values for the first order sorting criteria?

```
my_dict = {' A': 0.6, 'AB': 0.6, 'ABC': 0.4}
```

My current code will select the key  `A` because it is first in the list of items that has the highest value `0.6`.

```
my_key = max(my_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

However, when there are multiple keys that have an equal value (`0.6`), I don't want to select the first item with the highest value, but instead **sort secondarily by the keys' string length** after *stripping whitespaces*.

So in ***pseudo-code***, I am looking for something that achieves the effect:

```
my_key = max(my_dict.iteritems(), keys=[highest_value, longest_key_str_length_after_strip])[0]
```

Which would give the key `AB` because its key length is longer than  `A` when calculating `len(x.strip())` when both values are `0.6`.

**Question: How can the above be achieved via some sorting function in Python 2, that is of good performance?** E.g. something akin to `max()` via a custom function.

---

#### Pandas analogous example

To give a concrete example, I made a mock-up solution in Pandas which accomplished the above – however it appears to be resource intensive to create DataFrames for this purpose, since I do this operation *many* times from *many* dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['Key', 'Value']) #Create DataFrame from dict.

df['Key_Strip_Len'] = df['Key'].str.strip().str.len()        #Create new column w/ string lengths of stripped keys.
```

`print df`:

> ```
>         Key      Value    Key_Strip_Len
> 0      " A"       0.6                 1
> 1      "AB"       0.6                 2
> 2      "ABC"      0.4                 3
> ```

```
df = df.loc[df['Value'] == df['Value'].max()]                #Keep only rows that have the highest value.

df = df.sort_values(by=['Key_Strip_Len'], ascending=False)   #Sort DataFrame by highest key string length.

my_key = df['Key'].values[0]                                 #Choose key in first row of column 'Key'.
```

`print df`:

> ```
>         Key      Value    Key_Strip_Len
> 1      "AB"       0.6                 2
> 0      " A"       0.6                 1
> ```

And `my_key == AB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple can be used to break ties:

```py
my_dict = {' A': 0.6, 'AB': 0.6, 'ABC': 0.4}

greatest = max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1], len( kv[0].strip() )))
print(greatest)
```

Output:

```
('AB', 0.6)
```